# Getting table information with plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

need help regarding PL/SQL code... I need to see information about every table in schema a user wishes to check but in my results view tables also appear and I do not need them...
I only need tables and their columns in a list for example: table 1 column 1, table 1 column 2, etc.
Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE table_info_proc( p_schema_name IN VARCHAR2) 
IS 
TYPE all_tab_columns_type 
IS 
  TABLE OF all_tab_columns%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 
  v_all_tab ALL_TAB_COLUMNS_TYPE; 
  l_row PLS_INTEGER; 
  v_schema      VARCHAR2(50); 
  v_table_count NUMBER(5); 
BEGIN 
  SELECT DISTINCT(owner) 
  INTO            v_schema 
  FROM            all_objects 
  WHERE           owner = p_schema_name; 

  dbms_output.Put_line ('SCHEMA NAME: ' 
  || v_schema); 
  SELECT * bulk collect 
  INTO   v_all_tab 
  FROM   all_tab_columns 
  WHERE  owner = p_schema_name; 

  l_row := v_all_tab.first; 
  WHILE (l_row IS NOT NULL) 
  LOOP 
    dbms_output.Put_line ( 'table: ' 
    || V_all_tab(l_row).table_name 
    || ' column: ' 
    || V_all_tab(l_row).column_name ); 
    l_row := v_all_tab.NEXT(l_row); 
  END LOOP; 
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO   v_table_count 
  FROM   all_objects 
  WHERE  object_type = 'TABLE' 
  AND    owner = p_schema_name; 

  dbms_output.Put_line ('NUMBER OF TABLES IN SCHEMA: ' 
  || v_table_count); 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data_found THEN 
  dbms_output.Put_line ('There is no schema named ' 
  || p_schema_name); 
END table_info_proc; 
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in plain `SQL`, no need of `PL/SQL`.

- ALL_TAB_COLUMNS describes the columns of the tables, views, and
  clusters accessible to the current user.
- DBA_TAB_COLUMNS describes the columns of all tables, views, and
  clusters in the database.
- USER_TAB_COLUMNS describes the columns of the tables, views, and
  clusters owned by the current user. This view does not display the
  OWNER column.

Read [*_TAB_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn20277.htm#REFRN20277)

```
SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name
  2  FROM all_tab_cols
  3  WHERE owner='SCOTT'
  4  /

TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME
--------------- ---------------
TABLE_NAME      DEPTNO
TABLE_NAME      ENAME
TABLE_NAME      EMPNO
SALGRADE        HISAL
SALGRADE        LOSAL
SALGRADE        GRADE
EMP             SYS_STSA11ZDTGW
                $SYV6W40D3EV5X5

EMP             DEPTNO
EMP             COMM
EMP             SAL
EMP             HIREDATE
EMP             MGR
EMP             JOB
EMP             ENAME
EMP             EMPNO
DEPT            LOC
DEPT            DNAME
DEPT            DEPTNO
BONUS           COMM
BONUS           SAL
BONUS           JOB
BONUS           ENAME

22 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**EDIT** If you still want to use `PL/SQL`, then,

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    FOR i IN
  3    ( SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE owner='SCOTT'
  4    )
  5    LOOP
  6      dbms_output.put_line('TABLE_NAME = '||i.table_name||' COLUMN_NAME = '||i.column_name);
  7    END LOOP;
  8  END;
  9  /
TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME = DEPTNO
TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME = ENAME
TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME = EMPNO
TABLE_NAME = SALGRADE COLUMN_NAME = HISAL
TABLE_NAME = SALGRADE COLUMN_NAME = LOSAL
TABLE_NAME = SALGRADE COLUMN_NAME = GRADE
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = SYS_STSA11ZDTGW$SYV6W40D3EV5X5
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = DEPTNO
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = COMM
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = SAL
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = HIREDATE
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = MGR
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = JOB
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = ENAME
TABLE_NAME = EMP COLUMN_NAME = EMPNO
TABLE_NAME = DEPT COLUMN_NAME = LOC
TABLE_NAME = DEPT COLUMN_NAME = DNAME
TABLE_NAME = DEPT COLUMN_NAME = DEPTNO
TABLE_NAME = BONUS COLUMN_NAME = COMM
TABLE_NAME = BONUS COLUMN_NAME = SAL
TABLE_NAME = BONUS COLUMN_NAME = JOB
TABLE_NAME = BONUS COLUMN_NAME = ENAME

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**EDIT 2** If you want to restrict the output only to tables, then,

```
SELECT a.table_name,
  a.column_name,
  c.object_type
FROM all_tab_cols A,
  all_tables b,
  all_objects c
WHERE A.table_name = b.table_name
AND   b.table_name = c.object_name
AND A.owner        ='SCOTT'
/
```

Comment: thx, but still not good, it lists views as well...my solution which i pasted gets the same results...

Comment: hmm, getting there, but i still need to use bulk collect and table of in the code as it is in my first paste...

Comment: I have given you the SQL. You can use it in PL/SQL the way you want to.